# angularjs with ng-repeat. cant access the data in controler when i use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use the following ng-model with ng-repeat and I tried to access the data in my controller but it seems that the data cant be accessed there.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="container">
    <fieldset data-ng-repeat="contact in choices">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.firstname'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.lastname'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.email'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.contact'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.adress'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.city'>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='contact.state'>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addcontact()">Add</button></td>
    </fieldset>
    <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>
    <div id="choicesDisplay">
        {{ choices }}
    </div>
</div>    
</div>    
</div>
```

And use the following ng-app

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.choices = [{
        id: 'choice1'
    }];
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
        $scope.choices.push({
            'id': 'choice' + newItemNo
        });
    };
    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };
    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
            console.log("in m new controler now");
            $scope.contactlist = response;
            $scope.contact = "";
        });
    };    
    refresh();
    $scope.addcontact = function() {
        console.log($scope.contact);
        $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.contact).success(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
                refresh();
            });
    };
});
```

I can't access the data in $scope for the dynamically added controls through ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

In order to acess the data you should use

```
   $scope.choices[index]
```

Index is the number of index you want to acces

Comment: but i m adding the controls dynamically , so how would i know whats the value of index

Comment: you must the index in the function for eg if you want to get index in the addcontact function it must be like  addcontact(contact.$index) in html

Comment: if you want to get latest  then in controller you must use var index= $scope.choices.length-1; and then use $scope.choices[index]